# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Falta el parámetro IN o OUT en el índice:: 1

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, exception

I tried to resolve this issue but i don't find any form to resolve this could you please help me with this, this configuration is with websphere

```
[14/08/17 15:18:54:242 CDT] 00000053 SystemOut     O [EL Warning]: 2017-08-14 15:18:54.227--UnitOfWork(-1037272639)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Falta el parámetro IN o OUT en el índice:: 1
Error Code: 17041
Call: select nvl(sum(exh.montopagoprimaneta),0) FROM midas.tdpagocoberturareasegurador exh  where exh.idtoplanpagoscobertura= :idtoplanpagoscobertura  and exh.idreasegurador= :idreasegurador  and exh.estatuspago= :estatuspago 
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="select nvl(sum(exh.montopagoprimaneta),0) FROM midas.tdpagocoberturareasegurador exh  where exh.idtoplanpagoscobertura= :idtoplanpagoscobertura  and exh.idreasegurador= :idreasegurador  and exh.estatuspago= :estatuspago ")
[14/08/17 15:18:54:242 CDT] 00000053 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB ha generado una excepción no esperada (no declarada) al invocar el método "getmontoPagadoReasegurador" en el bean "BeanId(DEV-MidasPersistencia#MidasPersistencia.jar#ContratoFacultativoFacade, null)". Datos de la excepción:Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Falta el parámetro IN o OUT en el índice:: 1
Error Code: 17041
Call: select nvl(sum(exh.montopagoprimaneta),0) FROM midas.tdpagocoberturareasegurador exh  where exh.idtoplanpagoscobertura= :idtoplanpagoscobertura  and exh.idreasegurador= :idreasegurador  and exh.estatuspago= :estatuspago 
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="select nvl(sum(exh.montopagoprimaneta),0) FROM midas.tdpagocoberturareasegurador exh  where exh.idtoplanpagoscobertura= :idtoplanpagoscobertura  and exh.idreasegurador= :idreasegurador  and exh.estatuspago= :estatuspago ")
```

Here the code

```
public Double getmontoPagadoReasegurador(PagoCoberturaReaseguradorId id){
        String queryString = "select nvl(sum(exh.montopagoprimaneta),0) FROM midas.tdpagocoberturareasegurador exh "
                + " where exh.idtoplanpagoscobertura= :idtoplanpagoscobertura "
                + " and exh.idreasegurador= :idreasegurador "
                + " and exh.estatuspago= :estatuspago ";
            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
            query.setParameter("IdToPlanPagosCobertura", id.getIdToPlanPagosCobertura());
            query.setParameter("IdReasegurador", id.getIdReasegurador());
            query.setParameter("estatusPago", PagoCoberturaReaseguradorDTO.PAGADO);
            return Utilerias.obtenerBigDecimal(query.getSingleResult()).doubleValue();
    }
```

Comment: can You clean-up this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the query parameters that you are passing. It is case sensitive. Made some corrections to you code. Please try now.

```
public Double getmontoPagadoReasegurador(PagoCoberturaReaseguradorId id){
        String queryString = "select nvl(sum(exh.montopagoprimaneta),0) FROM midas.tdpagocoberturareasegurador exh "
                + " where exh.idtoplanpagoscobertura= :idtoplanpagoscobertura "
                + " and exh.idreasegurador= :idreasegurador "
                + " and exh.estatuspago= :estatuspago ";
            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
            query.setParameter("idtoplanpagoscobertura", id.getIdToPlanPagosCobertura());
            query.setParameter("idreasegurador", id.getIdReasegurador());
            query.setParameter("estatuspago", PagoCoberturaReaseguradorDTO.PAGADO);
            return Utilerias.obtenerBigDecimal(query.getSingleResult()).doubleValue();
    }
```

Comment: Let me try and i tell you, if this issue is solved thanks for your comment and your help